# Set correct order of bibliography using latex+bibtex

Tags: latex, tex, bibtex

So, I have an .tex and .bib files and I need my bibliography list to be on right order - appearance in text (now it is like in .bib file).
How to do it?
.tex file:
\bibliography{texfile}{}
Honestly, I've tried to use search, but didn't succeed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what you are asking. Can you provide a more detailed explanation? Does [this link](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/) help or is it too basic?

Comment: Maybe what you are missing is `\bibliographystyle{plain}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{your_bib_file_without_extension}
```

The `unsrt` option orders the references as they appear in text.